# iOS 14 - Source app's responsibility - Display ads that the ad network signs

Tags: ios, ios14, mobile-ad-mediation, skadnetwork

I have little bit of confusion regarding the second point mentioned for the source app's responsibility in documentation of [SKADNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork).

1. Add the ad network’s ID to its Info.plist.
2. Display ads that the ad network signs.

First part is done. I have addded the ad network IDs in my `info.plist`.

Regarding the second part **`Display ads that the ad network signs`**.

Is this something I need to do? Going through the documentation I see the keys but if I do have to implement it what would the value be?

According to [this](https://adtechexplained.com/skadnetwork-explained/) article

> 2. ***Display the ads that the ad network signs*** -
>    While this is listed under "Source App" this responsibility will ultimately fall on the ad network SDK if it is going to be handling displaying ads in the app. In any case, the source app must use a set of keys when they call the loadProduct() method to describe a specific impression from the ad network's ad in order to associate an app install with an ad campaign.

Does this means this part of code is handled by the ad sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[according to this article it seems like sdk will handle](https://incipia.co/post/app-marketing/skadnetwork-apptrackingtransparency-in-ios-14/)

> Displaying an advertised product/initiating a validation involves
> calling the loadProduct(withParamters:completionBlock:) method, which
> requires a signature key that the ad network generates, known as the
> SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkAttributionSignature.

Comment: That is true. The confusion arises from the point being under the Source app's responsibility.